execve system call returning an unexpected output
So I've been working on a mini project in C about piping and processes in Linux.
A program is executed like this:
./a.out "file1" "cmd1" "cmd2" "file2"
It should behave same as:
< file1 cmd1 | cmd2 > outfile
So in my header file I have struct
typedef struct s_pipex
{
    int fd1;
    int fd2;
    char    **envp;
    char    **env;
    t_list  *list;
}   t_pipex;

where t_list is

typedef struct s_list
{
    char        **cmd;
    struct s_list   *next;
}   t_list;

In my main function I have a
t_pipex    *pip_init(t_pipex *pip, int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
which uses access system call to check if the files exist, if output file doesn't exist it creates it and finally opens them at fd1 and fd2 with appropriate modes and permissions. It then goes through the environment variables, find PATH, splits it based on ':' separator and stores it into env. Then it creates a singly linked list for from 2nd and 3rd arguments that were passed on execution. Also, it's worth mentioning that I am using a linked list because later on, I will implement a feature for entering unlimited number of commands. Next thing main does is it calls the pipex function.
int pipex(t_pipex *pip)
{
    pid_t   pid1;
    pid_t   pid2;
    int flag;
    int pipfd[2];

    flag = 0;
    if (pipe(pipfd) == -1)
        return (-1);
    pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1 == -1)
        return (-1);
    else if (pid1 == 0)
    {
        child1(pip, pipfd);
        return(-1);
    }
    pid2 = fork();
    if (pid2 == -1)
        return (-1);
    else if (pid2 == 0)
    {
        child2(pip, pipfd);
        return (1);
    }
    close(pipfd[0]);
    close(pipfd[1]);
    waitpid(pid1, NULL, 0);
    waitpid(pid2, NULL, 0);
    return (WEXITSTATUS(flag));
}

Basically, all this function does is it creates a pipe for the 2 child processes, runs the forks child processes and runs the functions that are supposed to execute the shell commands and waits for them to finish.
Here is the code for child1 and child2. I know am not checking for all the possible errors, but this is still in development, so I am just trying to get it to work.
int child1(t_pipex *pip, int pipfd[])
{
    int acc;

    dup2(pip->fd1, STDIN_FILENO);
    dup2(pipfd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(pipfd[0]);
    close(pipfd[1]);
    acc = access_check(pip);
    if (acc != -1)
            xecve(ft_strjoin(pip->env[acc], pip->list->cmd[0]), pip->list->cmd, pip->envp);
    return (-1);
}

int child2(t_pipex *pip, int pipfd[])
{
    int     acc;
    t_list  *tmp;

    tmp = pip->list->next;
    dup2(pipfd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    dup2(pip->fd2, STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(pipfd[0]);
    close(pipfd[1]);
    acc = access_check(pip);
    if (acc != -1)
        execve(ft_strjoin(pip->env[acc], tmp->cmd[0]), pip->list->cmd, pip->envp);
    return (-1);
}

access_check is a simple functions that returns -1 if the command cannot be found in PATH or the index at which it's path is located in pip->env.
So I was expecting the code to execute first command, pipe it to the second, execute second command and write it to a file. Instead, whenever I run it with a command that depends on redirecting the input to it, such as grep or cat, I got errors. When I run it like:
./a.out "infile" "grep foo" "wc -l" outfile
I would get
grep: foo: No such file or directory
I tried printing all the file descriptors, path, commands, arguments, everything is set up properly, but for some reason it doesn't work as expected. Also, sorry if I made some noob mistakes, I just starting out, so forgive me and thank you for your time.

xecve (sic) <- that's not the code you are running. Instead of paraphrasing the code, please provide a [mre] that would allow us to reproduce your problem..

If grep thinks foo is a file instead of a string to search, you probably have a problem around argument parsing/passing. Which is a part of the code you have not shared.

Are char ** that you give to execve are NULL terminated ? What errno is saying ?
You pipe/dup2 logic seems fine.

Please try to : 1) Close pip->fd1 in child1, close pip->fd2 in child2, 2) Make sure char ** that receive execve are NULL terminated. 3) add waitpid(-1, NULL, 0); at the beggining of child2, to let him wait for others child process (not sure of this third proposition).

Sorry for late response guys, I had technical issues.
@teapot418 Sorry for that, but this is a school project and I am allowed to use very limited set of functions. Therefore I have a whole library of functions for doing very simple stuff like combining strings etc and I would have to change entire code in order for you to be able to reproduce it.

@polozer execve doesn't fail and errno gets set to 2, no such file or directory, guessing it's because it's trying to run grep on "foo" file. Seems to me that the compiler thinks I am passing more than 1 parameter, which is odd because I tested every single value manually with printf and everything seems correct.
I tried all the things you said and everything was the same, no difference in the output.

@IgorMićović can you link a github repository that compile with your project ? I'll check that if I have the time. Need to understand what's hapenning here

@polozer Thank you for the help, but I just figured out what's the problem and it wasn't anything interesting in particular. As you can see in the child2 function, I am using execve, but before that I create a t_list pointer to hold the second command (2nd node in the list). But I am not passing that to execve, instead I am passing the pip->list->cmd as the second parameter. Like I suspected, it was a a newbie error. Thanks for the help anyways.

@IgorMićović it reassure me, because I wasn't seeing any error in the code. Have a good time coding in 42 mate, thats a nice school and a nice way to learn. Enjoy !
